# Abel-Ruffini theorem and eigenvalues symmetric matrices

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry

Hi, I'd like to know whether Abel-Ruffini theorem implies that is not possible to find a general algebraic expression for the eigenvalues of a nxn symmetric matrix. In other words, if I know that my characteristic equation has real coefficients and real roots only, is it possible in principle to obtain a general solution in terms of radicals?

Thanks

Answer (score 4):

Explicit example: the symmetric matrix $$\pmatrix{ 1&1&1&0&0\cr 1&0&1&1&0\cr
1&1&0&1&1\cr 0&1&1&0&0\cr
0&0&1&0&1\cr} $$
has characteristic polynomial ${t}^{5}-2{t}^{4}-5{t}^{3}+5{t}^{2}+5t-3$,
which according to Maple has Galois group $S(5)$ and is therefore not solvable by 
radicals.

Answer (score 3):

No, it is not possible. There is a nice proof of the fundamental theorem of algebra which uses the fact that $\mathbb C$ is a quadratic extension of $\mathbb R$. This proof shows that if we were able to solve by radical polynomial equations whose roots are all real, then we should be able to do so when the roots may be complex.

By the way, the question about solving polynomials is equivalent to that about calculating eigenvalues: - in the complex case, one passes from a polynomial $P$ to a matrix by taking the companion matrix, - in the real case, there is an explicit construction of a tridiagonal symmetric matrix with given characteristic polynomial when the latter has real roots.